# How to exclude a field from @JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)

Tags: java, jackson

I have annotated a POJO with `@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)` to exclude all **null** fields while serialization/deserialization.
But now I need to exclude one of the fields from this behaviour. ie - I want to send over the value of a field as **null** if it has a **null** value.
There is some update in legacy code which has put me in this situation.

How can i achieve this?

**Edit:**

Would using a JSONSerialize(include=CustomSerializer.class) give higher precedence to the CustomSerializer?

Comment: Try `@JsonSerialize(include=Include.ALWAYS)` on your field

Comment: Thanks @Hector. But perhaps `include` is deprecated. Should i try using a custom serializer? Will that not be suppressed by the annotation at class level?

Comment: Oops, I didn't know. Maybe using custom deserializer with `using` attribute in the annotation has more priority than the annotation at class level. Just try it and tell us ;)

Comment: I am not quite able to use a custom serializer as well as the value to be set is `null`  and what I have tried to use is `JsonSerializer` where writeXXX(null) would be an ambiguous statement.

Answer (score 2):

Use `@JsonInclude(Include.ALWAYS)` annotation on your field. This will override `@JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)` on the class level.